# Не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: visual-studio, c++

В VS скомпилировал код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a;
    cout<<"Hallo";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a;
    cin>>a;
    return 0;
}
```

Выдало 0 ошибок, но когда нажал Ctrl+F5 в консольном окне появилось сообщение:
"C:Users...Pro.exe" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Как запустить программу?

Comment: @VlaDDushka заключите текст сообщения в обратные апострофы (те, которые на клавише "ё")

Answer (score 1):

Не рекомендовал бы Вам добавить #include "stdafx.h" в Ваш проект. Всё-таки C++ кроссплатформенный язык и в Вашем приложении вполне можно обойти и без этого include, характерного для платформы Windows. Тогда Ваш может компилироваться, без внесения дополнительных изменений под разные платформы. Вообще для изучения C++ советую использовать компилятор gcc.

Comment: Про gcc - золотые слова.

Answer (score 0):

1. Запускаете Visual C++ 2010 Express.
2. Создаете консольное приложение Win32.
3. Добавляете ваш код после строки `#include "stdafx.h"` вместо кода шаблона.
4. Жмете F7, затем F5 - и все работает.

Comment: Неужели стандартное

      #include <iostream>
      int main() {
          std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
      }

не будет работать без `#include <stdafx.h>`? Как всё запущено! Но я не верю.

Comment: Конечно, будет. Просто в настройки проекта надо будет некоторые изменения внести.